# Google Chrome is not starting

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on dual boot. I've looked for many solutions and tried them all but Chrome never starts; the logo appears on the left but no window opens.

I downloaded the deb file on google chrome website and installed it through Ubuntu Software, but it doesn't start.

I have tried installing it through the command line with

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I have checked with `uname -a` and my system is 64 bit. I have also tried `gdebi` with the same result.

My repository universe is up to date.

I only have one display in settings>displays> so I can't turn off built-in display nor check the mirror display (I read it could be the problem as I also have a graphic card but it seems it is not in my case).

Here is what I get in the command line when I try to run Chrome from it ( the message is the same, whatever the method I used to install Chrome):

```
~$ google-chrome
[11831:11831:1122/114854.195473:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[11831:11831:1122/114854.195493:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/basil/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[11831:11831:1122/114854.195508:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/basil/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[11831:11831:1122/114854.195515:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(280)] Failed to create /home/basil/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: Permission denied (13)
[11831:11831:1122/114854.195538:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[11831:11831:1122/114854.195564:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/basil/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[11831:11831:1122/114854.195622:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1498)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
[11831:11868:1122/114854.209297:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(108)] Failed to launch GPU process.
```

Any new approach will be much appreciated

Comment: Have you deleted the configs folder yet? I have to ask because you mention "many solutions" without describing what you actually tried already...

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't remember every topic I followed but I tried to mention all the solutions I could remember.

I definitely didn't try that, how should I proceed? where is the configs folder located?

Comment: Try `sudo rm -r /home/basil/.config/google-chrome/`.

Comment: You also might just want to review the permissions on your entire `/home` directory including owner are r+w.

Comment: removing the configs folder  worked ! thx a lot 
Would you have a short explanation? what was this config folder and why did it prevent chrome from running?

Comment: I've added a short explanation in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that you have no permission to access `/home/basil/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock`, which probably means it isn't owned by you. This is probably due to running Chrome as root (using `sudo`), which shouldn't be done.

Try `sudo rm -r /home/basil/.config/google-chrome/` to remove Chrome's configuration files for your user.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

However, i did not run chrome using sudo.

Can it be run as root without using sudo? because of some bad configuration?