# Snap chromium ERROR:process_singleton: Failed to bind

Tags: permissions, snap, chromium

When starting chromium installed by snap in ubuntu, I'm getting

`ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(1080)] Failed to bind() /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium SingletonSocket: Operation not permitted`

It's unlike the following, as I don't even have a `~/.config` folder.

- [Chrome won't install or launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010802/chrome-wont-install-or-launch)
- [Google Chrome is not starting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979092/google-chrome-is-not-starting)

and `/tmp` folder LGTM as well:

```sh
$ stat /tmp
  File: /tmp
  Size: 12288       Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 10302h/66306d   Inode: 1551        Links: 15
Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)

# creating the folder myself OK too:
$ mkdir /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.p4CAxj
$ rmdir /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.p4CAxj

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Full error log:

```
[40378:40378:0202/162457.837469:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(1080)] Failed to bind() /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.p4CAxj/SingletonSocket: Operation not permitted (1)
[40378:40378:0202/162457.838481:ERROR:chrome_main_delegate.cc(555)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the security rules, not a problem with missing files. You could disable snap confinement but that is a huge risk for a web browser